# Spring Boot database hostname DNS change

Tags: java, spring-boot, digital-ocean

I'm looking into using DigitalOcean's new managed database options for use with my Spring Boot application. They provide you with a hostname that points to the database, however, during weekly updates or in the event that it fails over to the standby node, the IP address behind the hostname changes.

How can I make sure that Spring automatically reconnects to the new, updated hostname?

Comment: If the IP is the only thing that changes, and you use the hostname to connect, your DNS should handle it for you

Comment: May be check in logs? Too little information about your app and configuration to solve it.

Comment: @ayrton That's what I expected. I think I just need to change the DNS cache expiration for Java. Also, it looks like DigitalOcean will be rolling out VPC support for managed databases soon, so it shouldn't be a problem down the road